# Probability of sum of independent events

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Let events $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$ be mutually independent such that $P(A_j) = (0,5)^j$
for $j = 1,2,3$. Find $P((A_1 \cup A_2)-A_3)$.

My solution:

$$ P((A_1 \cup A_2)-A_3) = $$
$$P((A_1 \cup A_2)\cap A'_3) = $$
$$  P((A_1 \cap A'_3)\cup (A_2 \cap A'_3)) = $$
$$  P((A_1 \cap A'_3)) + ((A_2 \cap A'_3)) - P((A_1 \cap A'_3) \cap (A_2 \cap A'_3)) = $$
$$  P((A_1 \cap A'_3)) + ((A_2 \cap A'_3)) - P(A_1 \cap A'_3 \cap A_2 \cap A'_3) = $$

Given that events are mutually independent we have:

$$  P(A_1)P(A'_3) + P(A_2)P(A'_3) - P(A_1)P(A'_3)P(A_2)P(A'_3) = $$
$$  P(A_1)(1-P(A_3)) + P(A_2)(1-P(A_3)) - P(A_1)P(A_2)(1-P(A_3))^2 = $$
$$  (1-P(A_3))(P(A_1) + P(A_2) - P(A_1)P(A_2)(1-P(A_3)) = $$
$$  (1-1/8))(1/2 + 1/4 - (1/2*1/4)(1-1/8)) = 287/512$$

Is that correct? The number seems bit off. Thank you.

Comment: $A_3'$ is not independent of itself $A_3'$.  You should have recognized that $A_1\cap A_3'\cap A_2\cap A_3' = A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3'$ and had simplified the expression to have *only one* copy of $A_3'$ to expand out.

Comment: You are right, I wasn't sure about that one. Applying your advice I am getting the same result as the accepted answer. (Which is a more elegant solution anyway). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let events $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$ be mutually independent such that $P(A_j) = (0,5)^j$
> for $j = 1,2,3$. Find $P((A_1 \cup A_2)-A_3)$.

A case can be made that this answer is defective, since I am not taking the time to examine the OP's (i.e. original poster's) work, line by line.  That really would be a lot of trouble.

$p(A_1) = (1/2), p(A_2) = (1/4), p(A_3) = (1/8)$ and 
$A_1, A_2, A_3$ are independent events.

$$p(A_1 \cup A_2) = 1 - p(A_1^{'} \cap A_2^{'}) $$

$$= 1 - [(1/2) \times (3/4)] = 1 - (3/8) = (5/8).$$

Let $C = A_1 \cup A_2 \implies p(C) = (5/8).$

Then, the desired computation is

$$p(C - A_3) = p(C \cap A_3^{'}) = (5/8) \times (7/8) = (35/64).$$